# How do i put a dropdown list of ALL my post in the sidebar menu?

Tags: posts, menus

In "Main Sidebar" i would like to add a dropdown list of ALL my post. How can i do that? I found various plugins and none of them did what i wanted (for example one only list the post i have on that page).

How might i put all my post into a dropdown/menu list in the sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    // query for all posts
    $your_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1' );

    echo '<select>'.
         '<option value="" selected="selected">Select a post</option>';

    // loop through posts
    while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
        echo '<option value="';
        the_permalink();
        echo '">';
        the_title();
        echo '</option>';
    endwhile;

    echo '</select>';

    // reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Obviously, that does nothing unless you bind some js/jQuery to the change event.

Answer (score 0):

You can show all post w/o jQuery using this bit of code:

```
<form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
<select name="page_id" id="page_id">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```